# Call a function with values in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I defined a function

```
def test_function(id):
.....
.....
.....
```

I was calling that function via

```
df = test_function('123')
```

but what I want to do now is, I have another Dataframe df2 =

```
values
123
354
645
456
176
```

I want to write an apply function which would take 1 value at a time from df2
and run my test_function instead of manually adding values.

and also my df should be appended for different values,
such that df contain a column name 'value' which would be the value selected one at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with [`DataFrame.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

*Notice: `[]` are necessary, because `pandas` function [`Series.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) - so `df2.values` return `numpy array` and `df2['values']` select column `values`. Same problem is with another column names with same names as some functions in pandas like `count`, `size`, `sum`...*

```
a = f2['values'].apply(test_function).values
print (pd.concat(a, ignore_index=True))
```

Comment: ` df['values']`  or ` df2['values'] `

Comment: Sorry `df2['values']`

Comment: And I am not sure about `df`, but it seems need same like `df['values']`.

Comment: i'm getting result as a `pandas.core.series.Series` because i stored it in `d3 = df2['values'].apply(test_function)`  df3 has 3 tables in it
can i concatenate this 3 tables into one and make type(df3) as dataframe instead of series.

Comment: So need `concat` ? Like `pd.concat([df31, df32, df33])` or `pd.concat([df31, df32, df33], axis=1)` ?

Comment: And it seems need `to_frame` - `print (df2['values'].apply(test_function).to_frame('name'))`

Comment: when i print df3 i get
`0         product_id_x product_id_y  count      dat...`

`1        product_id_x product_id_y  count      date...`

`2        product_id_x product_id_y  count      date...`
`Name: Leaf_Category_id, dtype: object`

`type(df3) pandas.core.series.Series`

and when i print `df3[0]` i get tables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129328/discussion-between-jezrael-and-s-ringne).

Comment: i tried using df_new = df.to_frame() but getting wrong result. check discussion

Comment: ok, you can go to discussion - click to link in 2 comments above.

Answer (score 0):

No need to call this function everytime, instead you do this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Val'])
df['Val']=list(df2['values'])
```